# How to disable requiring a password for mount USB - Flash drive

Tags: raspbian, usb, mount, password

I cant find the answer, How can I disable requiring password to mount Flash drive, Just plug USB and open folder without password.

[image]

Comment: Have you tired to plug this drive in another computer? It require the password?

Comment: raspberry (raspbian)  require password NOT flash drive. I tried several pendrives and SD - card and the same thing every time.

Comment: you change something in user settings?you are logged with `pi` user or not?

Comment: i'm logged with pi user via HDMI to TV and via VNC-server. in both cases the same problem

Only from the root level  does not ask for a password.



I'v tried  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByTx6U-HcbE

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `pmount` could be your new buddy.

> pmount is a wrapper around the standard mount program which permits normal users to mount removable devices without a matching /etc/fstab entry.

[Debian -- Details of package pmount in stretch](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/pmount)

to install: `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install pmount`

Answer (score 0):

I have updated RPI to a newest version and now this error is no longer occurs with the connected device via HDMI (PI user does not require password authorization). But still requires password authorization when connecting via the VNC-server